# regular expression - 2nd occurence between slashes from the end

Tags: python, regex

I got this string:

```
adhoc_test/test_data1/my_cost_analysis/20200422_114207_00005_qftfg_d445c480-2ff9-4161-a1fa-8ca8e0ba2663.gz
```

and I need to write regular expression to get `my_cost_analysis` (in python).

There can be unlimited number of / before `my_cost_analysis`. But it will always be 2nd level from the end. (i.e. always ending with `my_cost_analysis/something.gz`). `my_cost_analysis` is just an example, this text can be anything.

So I need to get any text that is 2nd level from the end. (between 2nd and 1st / from the end, there can't be any other / inside the text).

Comment: Why do you need a *regex*? Python has better tools for dealing with what is clearly a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regexp, of course, but in this case you don't have to:

```
s = 'adhoc_test/test_data1/my_cost_analysis/20200422_114207_00005_qftfg_d445c480-2ff9-4161-a1fa-8ca8e0ba2663.gz'
second_from_end = s.split('/')[-2]
```